# how to get that image to be display in homepage instead of the video file

Tags: sharepoint

Actually i have doubt to proceed in below scenario.

I have created 1 video library in sharepoint 2010 having 1.wmv file uploaded for that respective video file has thumbnail image added how to get that thumbnail image to be display in homepage instead of the video file.

on clicking on thumb nail i need to play respective video file(URL).the Thumbnail image will change whenever new video file is uploaded so the application only fetches latest uploaded thumbnail with respective video file attached to particular thumbnail image how to do this task.please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in Video library in SP2010, so I guess what you mean is an Asset Library.
If that is your case, just add a web part on your main site and to display your item, and configure it to return **one** record and sort by **created time**.